# Abaqus - How to apply initial conditions as plastic strain?

Tags: abaqus

I m trying to apply to apply plastic strains initial conditions in Abaqus as you can see below :

```
** ----------------------------------------------------------------
*Initial Conditions, type=PLASTIC STRAIN 
test_elements, 0.338, -0.276, -0.0618, 0.0447
**
** STEP: Step-1
```

This part of code works in case of Stresses but not for plastic strains... The calculation presents no errors, abaqus runs but when i check the results, it doesnt consider my plastic strain...

----EDIT LATER---
An example of INP file :

```
*Heading
** Job name: dernier1 Model name: test_plastic
** Generated by: Abaqus/CAE 6.13-1
*Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO
**
** PARTS
**
*Part, name=PART-1-1
*Node
      1,           0.,       -13.75,           3.
      2,         -15.,       -13.75,           3.
      3,         -30.,       -13.75,           3.
      4,           0.,       -13.75,           0.
      5,         -15.,       -13.75,           0.
      6,         -30.,       -13.75,           0.
      7,           0.,          2.5,           3.
      8,     -15.3125,          2.5,           3.
      9,      -30.625,          2.5,           3.
     10,           0.,          2.5,           0.
     11,     -15.3125,          2.5,           0.
     12,      -30.625,          2.5,           0.
     13,           0.,        18.75,           3.
     14,      -15.625,        18.75,           3.
     15,       -31.25,        18.75,           3.
     16,           0.,        18.75,           0.
     17,      -15.625,        18.75,           0.
     18,       -31.25,        18.75,           0.
*Element, type=C3D8R
1,  7,  8, 11, 10,  1,  2,  5,  4
2,  8,  9, 12, 11,  2,  3,  6,  5
3, 13, 14, 17, 16,  7,  8, 11, 10
4, 14, 15, 18, 17,  8,  9, 12, 11
*Nset, nset=SET-1, generate
  1,  18,   1
*Elset, elset=SET-1, generate
 1,  4,  1
** Section: Section-1-SET-1
*Solid Section, elset=SET-1, material=MATERIAL-1
,
*End Part
**  
**
** ASSEMBLY
**
*Assembly, name=Assembly
**  
*Instance, name=PART-1-1, part=PART-1-1
*End Instance
**  
*Nset, nset=SET-1, instance=PART-1-1, generate
 1,  6,  1
*Elset, elset=SET-1, instance=PART-1-1
 1, 2
*Elset, elset="test_elements", instance=PART-1-1
 1, 2
*Elset, elset=_SURF-1_S1, internal, instance=PART-1-1
 3, 4
*Elset, elset=_SURF-1_S1_1, internal, instance=PART-1-1
 3, 4
*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=SURF-1
_SURF-1_S1_1, S1
*End Assembly
*Amplitude, name=AMP-1, time=TOTAL TIME, definition=PERIODIC
1,              5.,              0.,              0.
             5.,              1.
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
*Material, name=MATERIAL-1
*Elastic
140000., 0.28
*Plastic
 50.,  0.
100., 0.2
** ----------------------------------------------------------------
*Initial Conditions, type=PLASTIC STRAIN
test_elements, 0.338, 0., 0., 0.
** 
** STEP: Step-1
** 
*Step, name=Step-1, nlgeom=NO
*Static
5., 5., 5e-05, 5.
** 
** BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
** 
** Name: Disp-BC-1 Type: Symmetry/Antisymmetry/Encastre
*Boundary
SET-1, ENCASTRE
** 
** LOADS
** 
** Name: SURFFORCE-1   Type: Pressure
*Dsload, amplitude=AMP-1
SURF-1, P, -5
** 
** OUTPUT REQUESTS
** 
*Restart, write, frequency=0
** 
** FIELD OUTPUT: F-Output-1
** 
*Output, field, variable=PRESELECT
** 
** HISTORY OUTPUT: H-Output-1
** 
*Output, history, variable=PRESELECT
*End Step
```

Comment: it will only work if your chosen material model supports an initial plastic strain.

Comment: how to support an initial plastic strain?

Comment: It should be in the manual under whatever material model you have specified.  The other issue to understand is what you have specified is the equivalent plastic strain.  It will only show direct on output if you plot the equivalent strain (`PEEQ`). Other strain measures (`PE`) only show new strain accumulation.

Comment: I will check thanks ;)

Comment: your set name `"test_elements,"` is invalid. (Did you want a comma as part of the name?). If I make that `testelements` (no quotes, no comma) and similarly change where you use it it works fine.  The initial strain contributes to `PE`  and `PEMAG` not `PEEQ`, my prior comment was off (sorry its been a while)

Comment: I have found the "error" i have to launch it in "command lines". Before my INP file was imported via File -> Import... Abaqus is strange sometimes... thanks for help

Comment: there is typically a pretty clear error message when you try to import a file containing unsupported elements

Answer (score 0):

So the only problem to get this to run was the extra set of quotes on test_elements? Not sure what the remaining problem is?

```
*Heading
** Job name: dernier1 Model name: test_plastic
** Generated by: Abaqus/CAE 6.13-1
*Preprint, echo=NO, model=NO, history=NO, contact=NO
**
**
*Node
      1,           0.,       -13.75,           3.
      2,         -15.,       -13.75,           3.
      3,         -30.,       -13.75,           3.
      4,           0.,       -13.75,           0.
      5,         -15.,       -13.75,           0.
      6,         -30.,       -13.75,           0.
      7,           0.,          2.5,           3.
      8,     -15.3125,          2.5,           3.
      9,      -30.625,          2.5,           3.
     10,           0.,          2.5,           0.
     11,     -15.3125,          2.5,           0.
     12,      -30.625,          2.5,           0.
     13,           0.,        18.75,           3.
     14,      -15.625,        18.75,           3.
     15,       -31.25,        18.75,           3.
     16,           0.,        18.75,           0.
     17,      -15.625,        18.75,           0.
     18,       -31.25,        18.75,           0.
*Element, type=C3D8R
1,  7,  8, 11, 10,  1,  2,  5,  4
2,  8,  9, 12, 11,  2,  3,  6,  5
3, 13, 14, 17, 16,  7,  8, 11, 10
4, 14, 15, 18, 17,  8,  9, 12, 11
*Nset, nset=SET-1, generate
  1,  18,   1
*Elset, elset=SET-1, generate
 1,  4,  1
** Section: Section-1-SET-1
*Solid Section, elset=SET-1, material=MATERIAL-1
,
**    
*Nset, nset=SET-1, generate
 1,  6,  1
*Elset, elset=SET-1
 1, 2
*Elset, elset=test_elements
 1, 2
*Elset, elset=_SURF-1_S1
 3, 4
*Elset, elset=_SURF-1_S1_1
 3, 4
*Surface, type=ELEMENT, name=SURF-1
_SURF-1_S1_1, S1
*End Assembly
*Amplitude, name=AMP-1, time=TOTAL TIME, definition=PERIODIC
1,              5.,              0.,              0.
             5.,              1.
** 
** MATERIALS
** 
*Material, name=MATERIAL-1
*Elastic
140000., 0.28
*Plastic
 50.,  0.
100., 0.2
** ----------------------------------------------------------------
*Initial Conditions, type=PLASTIC STRAIN
test_elements, 0.338, 0., 0., 0.
** 
** STEP: Step-1
** 
*Step, name=Step-1, nlgeom=NO
*Static
5., 5., 5e-05, 5.
** 
** BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
** 
** Name: Disp-BC-1 Type: Symmetry/Antisymmetry/Encastre
*Boundary
SET-1, ENCASTRE
** 
** LOADS
** 
** Name: SURFFORCE-1   Type: Pressure
*Dsload, amplitude=AMP-1
SURF-1, P, -5
** 
** OUTPUT REQUESTS
** 
*Restart, write, frequency=0
** 
** FIELD OUTPUT: F-Output-1
** 
*Output, field, variable=PRESELECT
** 
** HISTORY OUTPUT: H-Output-1
** 
*Output, history, variable=PRESELECT
*End Step
```